# Copy without namespace with criteria in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0

I'm using this template for copying without namespace:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()| processing-instruction()" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

this works. But I want it to copy without certain namespace rather than all namespace. For example I want to ignore few namespaces like `http://test.com`, `http://test2.com`, the copy should remove only these namespaces, not all the namespace.

Example:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xxx="http://include.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:zzz="http:test.com" >
   <zzz:element>
   </zzz:element>

   <xxx:complexType>
   </xxx:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Here `zzz` namespace should be removed but preserve `xxx` as `zzz` *only* matches `http://test.com`, so the output will be

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xxx="http://include.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <element>
   </element>

   <xxx:complexType>
   </xxx:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could we have an example to test against: [mcve]

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be confusing between moving elements to a different (or no) namespace and copying namespaces (i.e. namespace declarations). You should only need to move the `zzz:` prefixed elements to no-namespace - and not care if the output contains a by now redundant namespace declaration:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http:test.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. If you prefer, you can do the same thing without declaring any prefix:

```
<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='http:test.com']">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: what you told is correct, but how I can make the `xsl:template match="zzz:*` to be like `match="namespace:<url-which-I-dont-want>"` ? Because namespace prefix can be any, so I need to match based on the url only. Any hint?

Comment: The namespace associated with the prefix is defined in the stylesheet; the prefix can be anything you want. If the XML changes to use another prefix for the same namespace, it will still work. -- I have edited the answer to make that clearer - and added an alternative approach that uses the namespace directly, without binding it to a prefix.

Comment: @Ant's As I said, you should not care about it as it makes no difference. Controlling the copying of namespaces is difficult in XSLT 1.0, and what works with one processor might not work with another. Why is this important to you?

Answer (score 0):

Use a template with higher priority to keep elements in given namespace:

```
<xsl:template match="*"
              mode="copy-no-namespaces">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xxx:*" xmlns:xxx="http://include.com"
              mode="copy-no-namespaces">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*"
              mode="copy-no-namespaces"
              priority="-10">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The first template strips namespaces from elements, the second retains namespace `http://include.com` in elements, and the last copies everything else.

The second template could use `xsl:copy` instead of `xsl:element`, but that would copy all namespaces in scope and you'd end up with redundant namespace declarations.

Comment: thanks. Cant we make it other way like expect `http://test.com` namespace, have everything else? rather than hard coded to match `xxx:*` ?